# CSS does not work with Google App Engine

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am building the guestbook application from the official GAE webapp2 tutorial with these files

**helloworld/app.yaml**

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

**helloworld/index.html**

```
    <html>
 <head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="/stylesheets/main.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
      {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
        An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"/></div>
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

**helloworld/helloworld.py** and **helloworld/stylesheets/main.css** identical to those in the tutorial.

```
import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment (
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(_file_)))

import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users


class Greeting(db.Model):
  """Models an individual Guestbook entry with an author, content, and date."""
  author = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
  """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
  return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')
        greetings_query = Greeting.all().ancestor(
            guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order('-date')
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'greetings': greetings,
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    # We set the same parent key on the 'Greeting' to ensure each greeting is in
    # the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be
    # consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group should
    # be limited to ~1/second.
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
    greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user().nickname()

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                              debug=True)
```

the css

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

When i run the code everything works as expected but the css is not applied

i) when i view source i do not even see the  tag to the css
ii) when i look at the log i get this weird error:

```
INFO     2012-07-27 02:59:11,921 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: The "weird" error labeled ii): it means the attempt to find the file `/favicon.ico` returned 404 not found. A favicon is completely unrelated to CSS.

Comment: its weird because there is no favicon in my code...

Comment: A lot of browsers automatically look for /favicon.ico, it's the icon that shows up in the browser tab.  Don't worry about it, it's not a problem.

Comment: @dragonx thanks...but it looks like there's no HTTP request for the css at all.

Comment: You said the view source didn't show the CSS link.  In that case I would expect it to not get the CSS.  When you get it working you should see the CSS link when you view source.  Somehow you're not reading the template correctly.  I'm guessing the template is the wrong place.

Comment: hmm? I copied and pasted your code and it ran with showing css, all I can think is that there is a permission problem? Unlikely though - I did have to change to __file__

Comment: you could type the path to your css file in your browser

Answer (score 3):

in the 4th line of helloworld.py, you have written `_file`_ but it should be `__file`__

if i make that change, the whole thing works for me. Also, I also get a GET request for the css file.

```
INFO     2012-07-28 17:19:17,895 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /stylesheets/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your test server is not serving your modified index.html, but it's serving your original index.html that doesn't have the CSS link tag.  Or it's potentially using a cached page.  Try clearing your cache or restarting the server.  Or make sure your update is properly saved.

Comment: tried this..this doesn't seem to be the issue...clearing my cache does not help

Comment: could it be a problem with jinja2

Comment: probably this line:  template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')

Make sure you're reading the correct index.html file as the template.

Comment: If you inspect the index.html file in the browser (or via curl), does it have the <link> tag? If you open the 'network' tab in the browser development console, do you see a request for the CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and so did other team members.

At first I was told to go back to version 1.6.2 of Google App Engine Launcher but that did not work so I then deployed through the terminal (using the old normal method of update.py) and it worked.

I guess GoogleAppEngine Launcher does not work with some projects.

Note: We are on the old M/S version of AppEngine.

Answer (score 0):

There is something drastically wrong with your call on stylesheets inside app.yaml. Try this, instead:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

# you missed this section. It allows all .css files inside stylesheets
- url: /stylesheets/(.*\.(css)) 
  static_files: stylesheets/\1
  upload: stylesheets/(.*\.(css))

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```